# Django cannot find images

Tags: django, image, backend, django-staticfiles

I use Django ,everythings works perfectly fine but i cannot load images.

My settings.py file

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]

STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')
```

My html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}[enter image description here][1]
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>First App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Yeah..! this is index.html file</h1>
    <img src="{% static "images/pic1.jpg"  %}" alt="Nothing to show">
  </body>
</html>
```

[Tree directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH2Dg.png)

Comment: show your project directory tree

Comment: uploaded at https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH2Dg.png

Answer (score 0):

Typo in settings.py, it's supposed to be

```
  STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]
```